# Mysql update/insert for existing users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a form which is used to get two inputs: user_avatar and user_backgroundpicture. I want to update(if existing user) or insert(if registering for first time) them from a single form.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
if(isset($_POST))
{
require '../_inc/db.php';
$Destination = '../Backgroundimages';
if(!isset($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name']))
{
    //die('Something went wrong with Upload!');
    $BackgroundNewImageName= 'background4.jpg';

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$BackgroundNewImageName");
}
else{
$RandomNum   = rand(0, 9999999999);

$ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name']));
$ImageType      = $_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

$ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
$ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

$ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);

//Create new image name (with random number added).
$BackgroundNewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$BackgroundNewImageName");

}



   require 'authenticationforupload.php';



      $sql1="UPDATE user SET user_backgroundpicture='$BackgroundNewImageName' WHERE user_username = '$user_username'";


$sql2="INSERT INTO user (user_backgroundpicture) VALUES ('$BackgroundNewImageName') WHERE user_username = '$user_username'";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username = '$user_username'");
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
mysql_query($sql1)or die(mysql_error());
header('location:../input.php?profile=updated');
}
else{
mysql_query($sql2)or die(mysql_error());
header('location:../input.php?profile=notupdated');

}  








    $Destination = '../uploads';
if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
{
    //die('Something went wrong with Upload!');
    $NewImageName= 'default.png';

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$NewImageName");
}
else{
$RandomNum   = rand(0, 9999999999);

$ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']));
$ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

$ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
$ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

$ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);

//Create new image name (with random number added).
$NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$NewImageName");


}



       $sql5="UPDATE user SET user_avatar='$NewImageName' WHERE user_username = '$user_username'";


$sql6="INSERT INTO user (user_avatar) VALUES ('$NewImageName') WHERE user_username = '$user_username'";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username = '$user_username'");
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
mysql_query($sql5)or die(mysql_error());
header('location:../input.php?profile=updated');
}
else{
mysql_query($sql6)or die(mysql_error());
header('location:../input.php?profile=notupdated');

}  
 ?>
```

The form works fine when both the user_avatar and user_backgroundpicture are uploaded. If any single one is uploaded and the other one is left as it is, the action of the sql simply blanks the entry for which the input is not given.

What I want is that if one input is given, only that input should be inserted into the database. The other one should be left as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/** Updates the database only if the file field isn't empty. **/
    if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile'])){ // ALTERNATIVES: ($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name']=='') or ($_FILES["BackgroundImageFile"]["error"] == 4)
            mysql_query($sql1)or die(mysql_error());
            header('location:../input.php?profile=updated');
        }
    } else {
```

---

**HINTS:**

- Refrain from using `mysql_*` functions.
- Try rewriting your code to make it less chaotic.

Comment: Still it doesn't work! Only works if both user_avatar and user_backgroundpicture are given. If only one input is given, the other one justs get blank.

Comment: You did make the suggested changes to both instances right? Near `mysql_query($sql5)` also?

Comment: `if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   if(!empty($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile'])){ // ALTERNATIVES: ($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name']=='') or ($_FILES["BackgroundImageFile"]["error"] == 4)
            mysql_query($sql1)or die(mysql_error());
            header('location:../input.php?profile=updated');
        }
    } else {
    mysql_query($sql2)or die(mysql_error());
    header('location:../input.php?profile=notupdated');

    }  
`

Comment: `if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   if(!empty($_FILES['ImageFile'])){ // ALTERNATIVES: ($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name']=='') or ($_FILES["BackgroundImageFile"]["error"] == 4)
            mysql_query($sql5)or die(mysql_error());
            header('location:../input.php?profile=updated');
        }
    } else {
    mysql_query($sql6)or die(mysql_error());
    header('location:../input.php?profile=notupdated');

    }  
   
`

Comment: Did you try any of the alternatives? `ALTERNATIVES: ($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name']=='') or ($_FILES["BackgroundImageFile"]["error"] == 4)` ? I'm also not certain about the many `header()`s present. The way your code is now, the script will have clashes.

Comment: Thanks! I made it to work.`($_FILES['BackgroundImageFile']['name'])` did the trick!